# PGSQL Trigger Function Write Exception to Log Table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

**Background**

I'm new to PostgreSQL and I'm having some issues with this trigger function, which I've obviously simplified considerably below. I could ask to help fix the query, but I think I can handle that, and what I'm more concerned about is that I have a lot of functions like this and I need a way to be able to have visibility into why it's failing, and which ones are failing.

**Question**

How can I catch exceptions that happen within this function and write them to some kind of log table so I can review and fix each one? Ideally I'd like to write the sql statement that failed to the log table as well so I can see specifically what went wrong. I've seen a few examples of similar things, but they don't seem to fit my scenario.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
   BEGIN
        IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN

            INSERT INTO my_table(...)
            SELECT ...
            FROM table_1 t1
            JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id               
            ON CONFLICT (id)
            DO UPDATE
            field1 = EXCLUDED.field1;

        ELSIF(TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN

            UPDATE my_table 
            SET ...
            FROM table_1 t1
            JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
            WHERE id = NEW.id;

         ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id= OLD.id;
        END IF;
      RETURN NULL;
   END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: 1. After catching the exception and logging it, do you want to rethrow? 2. What version of PG?

Comment: You cannot get the triggering statement, but you can catch an exception in a `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION ... END` block.

Comment: It's versison 10.5. I think I want it to just fail silently and log the result and I can monitor and fix issues as they arise. It's currently failing silently, but I have no visibility, which is the problem.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe What about the actual sql within the trigger? Like, if it failed on an update, could I get the statement that executed within the update part of my trigger? One thing that makes it hard to triage is I have to replace NEW.myfield with actual values...there must be a better way, but the way I'm doing it is cumbersome.

Comment: You cannot get the failing query. What you can get is [information about the error](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-EXCEPTION-DIAGNOSTICS) and [trigger related information](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example, using a normal function rather than a trigger, though it's really the same thing in as far as how to log:

Table to store errors:

```
CREATE TABLE errors (id SERIAL, sql_state TEXT, message TEXT, detail TEXT, hint TEXT, context TEXT);
```

Function which does work and has the exception handling/logging:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func()
    RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    _sql_state TEXT;
    _message TEXT;
    _detail TEXT;
    _hint TEXT;
    _context TEXT;
BEGIN
    PERFORM 1 / 0;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS
            _sql_state := RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
            _message := MESSAGE_TEXT,
            _detail := PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL,
            _hint := PG_EXCEPTION_HINT,
            _context := PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;

        INSERT INTO errors (sql_state, message, detail, hint, context)
        VALUES (_sql_state, _message, _detail, _hint, _context);
END
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

After calling the function, the `errors` table contains:

[image]

See https://rextester.com/BQPG27732

Context shows a call stack of sorts. You could add more error-related fields of course, I only chose a handful of those available in `GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS`